# Battery Percent/Capacity elaboration in power statistics

Tags: power-management, laptop

In power statistics under the battery, I noticed that it gives me a "Percentage" and "Capacity" in percent.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure I understand this right, but does this mean that the battery's capacity is now 34.7% of the original capacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge:

Capacity indicates the total capacity of the battery vs. its rated capacity.  Therefore, if you have a battery with a rated capacity at full charge of 1000mAh, your max battery capacity is now only 374 mAh, which means the battery has degraded due to use or time and can no longer hold its typical level of 'max rated charge'.

Using that same example battery rating, of that 374 mAh, your battery is at 95% current capacity (percentage of the max capacity the battery can now hold), which is about 355 mAh.

I don't know what the rating on your battery is, but with this information you can probably determine what its current charge level is as well as exactly how much battery life your battery can still hold.

THIS SAID, with a battery that only has 37.4% of its rated capacity as what it can actually hold, you might want to consider replacing the battery at this point.